# should rsyslog TLS configuration work after CA/machine certificate expiry?

Tags: ssl, redhat, rsyslog

I have done tls configuration between two nodes (client and server).
i want to know what will happen if either one of the certificate ca.pem(CA certificate) or machine certificate get exipred.

rsyslog communication will stop working?

```
#$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

#certificate files for a client
#$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/tlscert/ca.pem
#$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/tlscert/machine-cert.pem
#$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/tlscert/machine-key.pem

#set up the action
#$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1
#$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The rsyslogd server will refuse new syslog packets and the remote logging will stop working. You would see in the `/var/log/[messages,syslog]` which certificate is causing the problem.

By the way, I always use `x509/name` as parameter to the directive `$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode` on production environments to ensure the certificate check. I actually don't know what this parameter `anon` means. It seems that it's use is only suggested to test environments.

Comment: Anon means not to check the certificate.